# Can I use <script async> to load babel-polyfill?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, babeljs

I have a modal dialog on my page that pops up when the user certain kinds of interation with the page.

I made it with React and used webpack to create a neat little bundle to include in my page via script tag.

Because it uses Generators and I have to support Internet Explorer 11, I need the [babel-polyfill](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/), so my HTML code looks like this:

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.9.1/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="/survey-modal.js" async></script>
```

What bothers me is that I'm loading the Babel polyfill synchronously. If I add *async* to the first script tag, my code works, but I'm not sure if this is deterministic, i.e. if the code only works by chance, because the polyfill finished loading before the survey-modal script.

Is it safe to use *<script async>* when loading the babel-polyfill from a CDN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it safe to use  when loading the babel-polyfill from
>   a CDN?

No it is not. `async` scripts execute "as soon as they are available" and order of execution is not guaranteed. So in the following example:

```
<script src="polyfill.min.js" async></script>
<script src="survey-modal.js" async></script>
```

there is a possibility that the "polyfill" script executes after "survey-modal". A better approach is as follows:

```
<script src="polyfill.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="survey-modal.js" defer></script>
```

`defer` scripts are downloaded after document has been parsed (so it does not block page rendering) but the order of execution is guaranteed.

PS: you mentioned that your code works when both scripts are async. Yes, this is by chance. It will work when polyfill is loaded from browser cache and may not work if it is fetched across network.

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee it will load before your modal if you use the async tag so I wouldn't use it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I only use generators when a user actually submits my dialog, by that time the polyfill will be surely be loaded. Is it safe to use async in a case like this? Or does the polyfill need to have finished loading when my main script starts running?

Comment: The problem is you can't guarantee it. If the request times out or takes longer than the time it takes for the user to submit then it will just fail and throw.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not deterministic and won't always work.

If you want, you can use throttling on chrome and see that when download speed is low, it won't work always.